# What's the effect of Spin operator $S_x$ on the spin operator $S_y$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

Hi my question is regrading the spin operators. When I calculated the product of $S_xS_y$  I found to be equal to $(iħ/2)S_z$ so I'm wondering what is the effect of the operator $S_x$ on the operator $S_y$ does it work as a rotation operator that rotate $S_y$ to $S_z$?